# Why finite group action on n torus induced a faithful action on its first homology group.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let G be a finite group of diffeomorphisms of the torus $T^n$
fixing some point p (i.e.p is fixed by every element of G). Why the action of G on $H_1(T^n; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^n$ is faithful.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you tell what a finite-order diffeomorphism fixing a point looks like?

Comment: This is not hard if, in addition, you assume that $G$ preserves a flat metric on $T^n$. It is considerably more difficult to prove in general (it follows from Corollary 9.7 in Bredon's book on compact transformation groups). Where did you find this claim?

Comment: yes, i have prove this when G preserve flat metric.